# javascript variable being overwritten by multiple calls to function

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which checks for the presence of a file. 
It's called 4 times, one after the other, checking for different files. 
It works fine for the first file, but doesn't work for subsequent ones. 
I think it must be because of the position of local / global variables, but can't figure it out... any ideas?

```
 <script>

function checkfile(fileNamePassed){

    var timerForLoadingResult=setInterval( function() { checkServerForFile(fileNamePassed); }, 4000 );
    function checkServerForFile(fileNamePassed) {    
          $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://myserver.com/'+fileNamePassed+'.txt',
                    type:'HEAD',
                    error: function()
                    {

                    },
                    success: function()
                    {
                        $("#"+fileNamePassed).hide();
                        clearInterval(timerForLoadingResult)  
                    }
                });
            }

}

</script>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what happens when you take the checkServerForFile(fileNamePassed)  function out of the scope of the checkFile(fileNamePassed) function ?

Comment: @daddygames - spot on - that did the trick... Many thanks for your quick reply / pointer :-)

Comment: @Jack you're welcome. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `checkServerForFile` from `checkfile` and pass in a **reference** to 
`timerForLoadingResult` when calling `checkServerForFile`.

I edited my answer to reflect some real data since I don't have a back-end to work with, but the concept is the same.

Removing the dependency of `timerForLoadingResult` and passing it in as a reference forces `checkServerForFile` to use it's referenced value instead of them all shares the same `timerForLoadingResult`.

You might also want to change the name of `timerForLoadingResult` since `setInterval` returns an `ID`.

From the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

> It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

```js
function checkfile(idPassed) {

  var timerForLoadingResult = setInterval(function() {
    checkServerForFile(idPassed, timerForLoadingResult);
  }, 4000);
}

function checkServerForFile(idPassed, timerForLoadingResult) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/justinjmnz',
    error: function() {

    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(idPassed + " found!"); // Your file was found

      $("#" + idPassed).append('<img src="' + data.avatar_url + '" height="50" width="50"/ >');
      clearInterval(timerForLoadingResult)
    }
  });
}

checkfile("foo");
checkfile("bar");
checkfile("foobar");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo">

</div>

<div id="bar">

</div>

<div id="foobar">

</div>
```